# What is SharePoint's relationship to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

All of the examples of client-side SharePoint development I've seen are using jQuery. What's the community's experience with other JavaScript frameworks?

I think Angular might be a stretch since it tries to "own" everything, but what about something like Vue.js?

Is jQuery in any sense "baked in" to SharePoint? I don't think so, since most of the examples I've seen demonstrate how to add the `SCRIPT` tag to the master page. Is it just used in examples due to ubiquity, or is there some officially relationship there?

Answer (score 1):

The is no official relationship there. jQuery is just the framework most developers in the SharePoint space prefer.